# Нужна ли запятая перед датой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"...до окончания проведения проверочных мероприятий и получения разъяснений от ветеринарной службы Ирана (?) с 28 февраля 2020 года временно приостановить ввоз из Ирана молока и молочной продукции через МАПП".

Нужна ли запятая перед датой? Перестроить предложение невозможно, так как это цитата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [правильная цитата](https://rns.online/consumer-market/Rossiya-ogranichila-postavki-moloka-iz-Irana--2020-02-28/):
*Россельхознадзором принято решение до окончания проведения проверочных мероприятий и получения разъяснений от ветеринарной службы Ирана **временно приостановить** с 28 февраля 2020 года ввоз из Ирана молока и молочной продукции через МАПП "Яраг-Казмаляр"*.

1. Если это цитата (как Вы утверждаете), то необходимо было обозначить и ее начало, и ее конец троеточиями — так как предложение приведено Вами не полностью.
2. Слова внутри цитаты (*временно приостановить*) нельзя переставлять.
3. Предложение громоздкое — упростим его:
   Принято решение до окончания проведения и получения разъяснений временно приостановить с 28 февраля 2020 года ввоз из Ирана молока и молочной продукции.

Причастных и деепричастных оборотов нет, сравнительных и пояснительных конструкций нет — запятые в этом предложении не нужны.